# Kubernetes serve static content with ingress

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, ingress, eks, kubernetes-volume

I have a simple Django application and on a regular EC2 instance nginx is a reverse proxy serving static files and proxying requests to gunicorn/wsgi backend app.

Should I have a separate deployment and service for nginx which will be able to access static data on a volume to serve it as well as proxy requests to django pods or

Is it possible to configure ingress to serve static data without extra nginx deployment?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47624902/serving-static-files-from-ingress-nginx

Comment: Did you find your solution?

Comment: @PaulRey, yes basically the solution you've described is the right one, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't configure your Ingress to serve static data (from your host files for example) alone because the Ingress resource is just a way to configure a way of understanding for Kubernetes on how to access a specific internal resource from outside the cluster.

> An API object that manages external access to the services in a cluster, typically HTTP.
> Ingress may provide load balancing, SSL termination and name-based virtual hosting.
> -- Ingress | Kubernetes - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

You must configure a web server (NGINX, Apache, etc.) with a mounted volume bound to your files. You'll also need a Service resource to publish the web server access internally. Then the Ingress resource will do the work.